# Changing HTML elements with Webbrowser

Tags: vb.net, webbrowser-control

I have a question, how to change HTML input value?

```
<select name="sys_lenght" aria-controls="systable" class>
<option value="20">Value 1</option>
<option value="40">Value 2</option>
<option value="80">Value 3</option>
</select>
```

I used this code

```
For Each Elementz In WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("select")
        If Elementz.Name = "sys_lenght" Then
            Elementz.setAttribute("value", "80")
        End If
    Next
```

But it doesn't change the input value, only the text "Value 3".
How can I solve this problem? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sys_lenght`'s value indicates which option with the specified value is selected. Thus if you set `sys_lenght.value` to `"80"` it will select `Value 3`.

To change the `value` of the ***currently selected option*** you have to get a reference to that first. You can do so by getting the [**`selectedIndex`**](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_select_selectedindex.asp) of `sys_lenght`, and then get the specific item from that index.

```
For Each Elementz In WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("select")
    If Elementz.Name = "sys_lenght" Then

        'Get the index of the selected option.
        Dim SelectedIndex As Integer = Integer.Parse(Elementz.GetAttribute("selectedIndex"))
        If SelectedIndex >= 0 Then
            'Get the option element from the resulting index.
            Dim SelectedOption As HtmlElement = Elementz.Children(SelectedIndex)
            SelectedOption.setAttribute("value", "80")
        Else 'No option selected.
            MessageBox.Show("No option selected!", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
        End If

        Exit For 'We found what we were looking for; stop looping.
    End If
Next
```

Comment: It's possible create a new custom value? E.g: 300?

Comment: @Giuseppe : Yes, you can set it to anything you want (whether the _website_ will accept that however is a different question).

Comment: Well, still not working for me, have no errors, but still not changing :\

Comment: @Giuseppe : What exactly is it you want to change? Am I right when I say you want to change the value of the selected `option`?

Comment: @Giuseppe : Are you _really_ sure that it doesn't actually change, and that the case isn't that it just don't appear so because the webpage rejecting the value? (whatever it does with it) - Because I just tested the code and it works fine for me.

Comment: @Giuseppe : Glad I could help! Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

First you have to understand how html open and close tag, you forgot to close the html selection option open tag i mean the last greter sign > then use javascript query to find the value within the option example

```
WebControl1.ExecuteJavascript('document.querySelector('option [value='your value']').selected=true;")
```

hope its help?

Comment: My mistake, fixed. But it doesn't affect nothing in this question

Comment: I saw that you have updated your answer, well... Still not working this javascript inject